# File name differs from already included file name only in casing.Vetur(1149)

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

There is nothing wrong with my folder structure or code.

However, after one time I change my folder name, Vetur keeps yelling this message to me.

I've tried the following things

1. completely delete repo and commit new git
2. reinstall Vetur
3. reboot the computer
4. remove node_modules

but the problem still there, how can I fix it?

---

2022 August Update:

It could still be reproducible, but the error description may differ; the reproduction:

1. Make a file named `Example.vue.`
2. import `Example.vue` into some other file
3. Change the name `Example.vue` to `example.vue`
4. Refactor the import statement to be `example.vue` as well.
5. The error message will appear.

Comment: Are you using Typescript? I am an am having a similar issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25460

Comment: Yes I'm using ts, I've already rename whole folder.

Comment: The same problem happens in Svelte.

Answer (score 10):

(Using vue.js v3) My solution was NOT to use the file extension '.vue':

Failed:

```
import X from './components/X.vue'
```

Succeeded:

```
import X from './components/X'
```

Comment: But vue cli next enforece you to add extension.

Comment: Cannot find module '../components/X' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: @JosephWang, can you give us a reference?

Comment: @user2495085 I've included the latest reproduction in the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the following properties in `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, just restart or reload your vscode